# Can't boot windows 7 after reininstalling ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, data-recovery, bootloader

I had Windows 7 at first and i needed Ubuntu for some project , so dual booted windows 7 alongside Ubuntu and was working perfectly . Then ,got some issues with Ubuntu so reinstalled Ubuntu again . Installed grub Customizer , but windows didn't get detected . Now after referring some posts , i installed Boot Repair and this is the report i got http://paste.ubuntu.com/10837169/ .

p.s  I don't mind the OS, but want my data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the boot-repair log, it appears that your Windows partitions had been removed, probably when you reinstalled Ubuntu.

At this point, there's not much hope for your data, but there are a few options you can try, if you're using a HDD. Your chances decrease the more you write to the disk (e.g. booting up Ubuntu), so shut down your computer immediately and don't write to or boot from the HDD. You're probably also out of luck if you're using a SSD.

You might be able to retrieve some data using `testdisk`, or going to a data recovery service if you can afford it. In the future, make sure you keep backups, especially for important data. (The 3-2-1 rule is a good rule to go by: 3 copies, 2 different media, 1 offsite)

Answer (score 0):

Seems, GRUB is unable to Locate your Windows & Partition.
I presume, that you are able to boot in Ubuntu, If so;
Here's what you should do,

1. Start Ubuntu
2. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
3. Type the command `sudo update-grub`
4. Type your password when asked
5. You should see similar output

   > ```
   >   rawbot@rawbot-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo update-grub
   >     [sudo] password for tez: 
   >     Generating grub configuration file ...
   >     Found background: /home/tez/Pictures/Anonymous.jpg
   >     Found background image: /home/tez/Pictures/Anonymous.jpg
   >     Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
   >     Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
   >     Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic
   >     Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-33-generic
   >     Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-31-generic
   >     Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-31-generic
   >     Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
   >     Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
   >     Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
   >     Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
   >     Found **Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1**
   >     done
   > ```
6. You will find that a Windows Partition has been detected, *Now you may **Reboot***
7. Now in GRUB Menu, you should be able to see Windows 7 in option list.

Hope this fixes your problem. And don't worry, data isn't lost, it's simply in accessible at the moment.

Comment: i did what you asked and this is what i got ` code` sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for adarsh: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
done
`code`

Comment: Ok, do not try any more attempts. Get a Windows CD and begin installation, There' a chance you will lose your data only on C Drive(Considering that is the drive where you installed Win OS previously). But if on boot(of WinOS), it asks you to UPGRADE during installation, proceed for it; Just after installation, go in C/Windows.old That's where you'll get your C: Drive's previous data. All the best.